# My ajax code not returning ajax value

Tags: ajax

I have checked so many links but i didn't succeeded using ajax in wordpress.

**Foooter.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
</script>
```

**custom.js**

```
jQuery('#elementid').on('keyup', jqueryfunction);

function jqueryfunction(id) {
    var value = jQuery(this).val();
    if (value.length > 3) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'value=' + value,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('.showcount').remove();
    }
}
```

**functions.php**
*`// I think i am wrong here. I don't know where to write this code`*

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
function mycustomfunction() {
    echo "Function found";
}

add_action('wp_ajax_mycustomfunction', 'mycustomfunction');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mycustomfunction', 'mycustomfunction');
```

In the console it only shows **0** but it should show **Function found**. Can someone please refer me where to write this code so that it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In above case your ajax request is not reaching your php function, thus it founds nothing. Update your jquery function with this

```
 function jqueryfunction(id) {
    var value = jQuery(this).val();
    if (value.length > 3) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'mycustomfunction',
                value: value,
                },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('.showcount').remove();
    }
}
```

as you can see that i added a parameter "action" which is name of your ajax request after wp_ajax_.

Also update your php function with

```
function mycustomfunction() {
    echo "Function found";
die; //wp_die();
}
```

Add die at end of your function , otherwise you will see a "0" with your ajax response.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I am glad it helped you @Tuku